# is this possible Bootstrap carousel thumbnail display 4 column in desktop and 2 column in mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm Trying to Display Bootstrap carousel in different views. like when it is diaplay on desktop it has 4 column and in mobile it will display 2 column.
this is my code. it is 4 column thumbnail view. but when i see in mobile view it will display item below. I find on google. i got this https://www.codeply.com/go/PKto9ssn0W/bootstrap-4-carousel-with-thumbnail-navigation. but its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>

.carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.left { left: -33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.right { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .next { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .prev { left: -33.33%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
                     <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
                            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">5</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">6</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--/carousel-inner-->
                    </div><!--/myCarousel-->
                </div><!--/well-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display two columns on mobile using col-xs-6 and 3 columns on desktop using col-md-4 that you have in your example code. If you want another column on desktop, all you need to do is change the class from col-md-4 to col-md-3.

I also added a height and overflow: hidden to the #myCarousel css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>

.carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.left { left: -33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.right { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .next { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .prev { left: -33.33%; }
#myCarousel { height: 250px; overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
}
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
                     <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
                            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">5</div>
                                    </div>            
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>


                           <div class="text-center">6</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/carousel-inner-->
                </div><!--/myCarousel-->
            </div><!--/well-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```